# Refactor: Removing flags

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a Java class such as:

```
public class className{
    public static void methodName(Object atr1, Object atr2, Object atr3, boolean flag){
        //Code here ...

        if(flag){
            executeASingleInstruction();
        }

        //Code here ...
    }
}
```

I know using flag parameters is a bad smell, and I would like to know If I could refactor this method in order to remove the flag parameter, or if it is better to keep this method the way it is right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that there are more things to consider refactoring in your code, but here I will focus only on the boolean parameter smell.

You can refactor it by splitting up the method and deciding which one of the new methods to use at the place of invocation.

This will make your intention more clear at the point where you invoke either of the methods, especially if they have nice, descriptive names.

If I recall correctly, there is a section about it in Robert C. Martin's book: [Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/)

```
public class className{
    public static void methodName1(Object atr1, Object atr2, Object atr3){
        encapsulation1(atr1, atr2, atr3);
        executeASingleInstruction();
        encapsulation2(atr1, atr2, atr3);
    }


    public static void methodName2(Object atr1, Object atr2, Object atr3){
        encapsulation1(atr1, atr2, atr3);
        // no execution of aforementioned instruction
        encapsulation2(atr1, atr2, atr3);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case there would be quite a lot of code duplicated. Which is worst? Duplicate code or using flags?

Comment: You can encapsulate the code before and after `executeASingleInstruction();` in their own methods. I will modify the code example to illustrate. In fact you should prefer this even if you don't split into two unflagged methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that atr1, atr2 and atr3 are all modified before and after calling executeASingleInstruction(). Although the code would work, I think it is not good to alter the objects passed as parameters in a method. ¿Is this option better than using flag?

Comment: As I mentioned there would be other things to refactor. Getting rid of the Boolean flag is just one part, and not the final picture, so the cost-benefit comparison should really only be made against the final result. Before the refactoring is complete, I would also suggest, inspired by Uncle Bob, that you change your method so that it does not change state in its parameters (i.e. avoid side effects) and secondly that you break it down into methods taking preferably one but at most two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static method, and you can use object properties if you need to set the flag, also you can provide the flag in the constructor.

```
public class ClassName{

private boolean flag;
//getter setter

public ClassName(){}

public ClassName(final boolean flag){this.flag = flag;}

public void methodName(Object atr1, Object atr2, Object atr3){
    //Code here ...

    if(flag){
        executeASingleInstruction();
    }

    //Code here ...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it static`enter code here`

```
public class className{
        public static void methodName(Object atr1, Object atr2, Object atr3, boolean flag){
            //Code here ...

            if(flag){
                executeASingleInstruction();
            }

            //Code here ...
        }

        private static void executeASingleInstruction() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```